# MySQL add condition to a query only when it is true

Tags: mysql

I want to apply the `gla.last_importation_date` to my query only if the date of importation for the transaction falls between the `start_date` and `end_date`. It should not be affecting the query if the date doesn't fall in between that date range. Below is my query

```
SELECT 
  gla.identifier,gla.name, gla.slug, gla.real_depth, gla.balance, 
  SUM(je.debit_record) debits, SUM(je.credit_record) credits
FROM general_ledger_accounts gla 
LEFT JOIN 
  (
   SELECT li.debit_record, li.credit_record, jle.transaction_date, li.general_ledger_account_id 
     FROM line_items li 
     JOIN journal_entries jle 
       ON jle.id = li.journal_entry_id 
     WHERE jle.transaction_date BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE 
   ) je 
ON je.general_ledger_account_id = gla.id 
WHERE 
     gla.type_letter IN ('I', 'E') 
OR 
(gla.last_importation_date BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE) 
GROUP BY gla.identifier, gla.name, gla.slug, gla.real_depth, gla.balance, gla.imported_balance;
```

Comment: *It should not be affecting the query if the date doesn't fall in between that date range* So when this condition is TRUE you want it in the query and when it is FALSE you don't. This is equivalent to not have the condition in any case!

Comment: If I remove the ```OR``` condition, the query works fine up to the point where there was an imported transaction, then it's results are wrong. However if I leave the ```OR``` condition, it returns all the fields which don't fall with the specified time period. I have also tried using ```AND IF``` but doesn't return the wanted results

Comment: Edit your question and provide there all the necessary clarifications as well as sample data and expected results.